# Remove non-alphabetic characters and more than one space from a string

Tags: ruby, regex

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here:

```
"#New    York".gsub(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/,"").strip
```

This regex should remove all non-alphabetic characters and all spaces greater than 1 space.

It should give me the following result:

```
"New York"
```

What is wrong with the regex?

Comment: no regex `"#New    York"[1..-1].split.join(' ')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `strip` with `squeeze`:

```
"#New    York".gsub(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/,"").squeeze(" ")
# => New York
```

Another way is to use a regex like

```
"  #New \t   York  ".gsub(/\s{2,}|[^\sa-zA-Z]/, ' ').strip
```

Or

```
"  #New \t   York  ".gsub(/(\s){2,}|[^\sa-zA-Z]/, '\1').strip
```

Here, `/\s{2,}|[^\sa-zA-Z]/` matches 2 or more consecutive whitespaces (`\s{2,}`) or (`|`) any char other than an ASCII letter or whitespace (`[^\sa-zA-Z]`). In case of `(\s){2,}`, the last whitespace captured will be inserted into the resulting string with the help of the `\1` placeholder.

See a [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/R9g6thxXLb).

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: [`(?:\s+(?=\s)|[^A-Za-z\s]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/cINiqW/1)

**Ruby code**:

```
"#New    York".gsub(/(?:\s+(?=\s)|[^A-Za-z\s]+)/, '')
```

Output:

```
New York
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/BJsVsk)